# Should "of" or "from" be used in this context, and why?

Tags: prepositions

Would you use "of" or "from" in the context of example (1)? Why? Or are they interchangeable? Thank you.

> Example (1): The profits **[of/from]** many factories are misstated.

My research: "From" seems to be the most frequent preposition in contexts similar to example (1) in books & newspapers (*for instance, see example (2) from a newspaper: "Company X said that profits from its Z division grew by 10%."*), BUT, for some strange reason that I cannot explain, "from" feels awkward to me in example (1), whereas I feel that "of" reads better.

Comment: In many contexts there's no "preferred" preposition in English. And in many *more* contexts, even if one particular preposition is far more common, that needn't imply others are "wrong". *The profits **by** many companies...* is imho stylistically "weak" in the *exact* cited context, but [the same preposition in several very similar contexts](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22profits+by+many+companies%22) is fine.

Comment: Neither. **Many factory profits are misstated on profit and loss statements**.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what research you did, but "of" seems to be used more, as indicated by [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=profits+from+businesses%2C+profits+of+businesses&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Both could be correct, depending on context and your point of view. "The profits of factories" sounds most idiomatic if you were speaking about many factories as separate business entities, each *having* profits of their own. But let's say one company had various business endeavours and drew income *from* those individual sources - they might say that they had profits *from* [x] and profits *from* [y]. So, a question might be, are you receiving the profits *from* anywhere? If they are going *to* you, or you are speaking from an observer's perspective where you are looking at the money coming from those entities, then use 'from'. Otherwise, use 'of'.

Comment: Thank you. I am having a hard time understanding this and how it applies to my case, and I am still hesitating. Basically, you seem to say that if the factories belong to various companies, one should use "of", whereas if the factories belong to one single company, one should use "from". The problem with the context in which I am using the sentence is that it includes both cases, which is maybe what makes me hesitate... Basically, I am making a general statement that refers to all firms & factories in an industry but that, as a sentence, applies to all factories within one firm (I think...).

Comment: @baitas You've taken it a little too directly. I'm not saying that the structure of the company determines which you should use - I'm saying your *perspective* matters the most. Something goes *from* one place *to* another. So, are you speaking from a perspective where you are receiving, or observing money coming *from* those places? Are you receiving the profits? Are you processing or assessing their income, perhaps their tax returns? If not, then use 'of'. This preposition implies belonging. The profits 'of' the business are the profits that belong to the business.

Comment: I still don't get it.  Should we use from in this case because we are talking about receiving/observing/processing/assessing or of because we are talking about belonging? To me both cases are possible because both alternative sides (**receiving/observing/processing/assessing** and **belonging**) are happening simultaneously.